# How to achieve gated content technique in Sitecore 9.3

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am trying to implement a feature called `Gated Content` in `Sitecore 9.3` that was possible in Sitecore 8.1 using a third-party module mentioned in the [link](https://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2016/06/30/gated-content-sitecore-module/) and was able to follow it easily until I hit the roadblock in implementing the success redirect of form override as mentioned in the link.

I don't see any processor in `Sitecore 9.3` which is equivalent to `Sitecore.Form.Core.Pipelines.FormSubmit.SuccessRedirect` in Sitecore forms so far. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can define the same type of save action and then do the same type of logic in Sitecore Forms as well.

Comment: @GauravAgarwal Thanks for the response, but as I stated in my problem statement I ran into the issue only when implementing the success redirect but not in implementing the Save actions in Sitecore forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve the behavior by setting the `RedirectUrl` on the `SubmitAction` directly like below.

```
formSubmitContext.RedirectOnSuccess = true;
formSubmitContext.RedirectUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer?.ToString();
```